# TFS 2010 not building specified configuration for all solutions

Tags: .net, tfs, csc

We've ran into a bug with `#if DEBUG` precompilation instruction that isn't working when deployed on a server.

Everything is going fine while we work locally. Even a local publish doesn't contain the code inside the `if DEBUG`. The problem occurs when we build the solution on the TFS build server.

Here's everything I checked, maybe a pair of fresh eyes will find something I overlooked.

## Project configuration

**Define DEBUG constant in Release configuration**

That's the project configuration (the one where we use `#if DEBUG`):

[image]

On my computer it works fine. When I switch to Release configuration, the code in the `#if DEBUG` doesn't get outputted to the dll.

## TFS Configuration

**Configuration Folder Path**

TFS uses a tfsBuild.proj file and the Configuration Folder Path should contain the directory where the file is. I double checked to make sure it targets the right one.

**SolutionToBuild**

That's the configuration section that defines the two solution that need to be built:

```
<SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/../../../PathToTheSolutionThatIsCorrectIDoubleChecked1/Solution1.sln">
  <Targets></Targets>
  <Properties>
  </Properties>

</SolutionToBuild>

<SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/../../../PathToTheSolutionThatIsCorrectIDoubleChecked2/Solution2.sln">
  <Targets></Targets>
  <Properties>
  </Properties>

</SolutionToBuild>
```

**ConfigurationToBuild**

Inside the tfsBuild.proj file is a section to tell TFS the configuration to use for the build. It is defined like this:

```
<ConfigurationToBuild Include="Release|Any CPU">
  <FlavorToBuild>Release</FlavorToBuild>
  <PlatformToBuild>Any CPU</PlatformToBuild>
</ConfigurationToBuild>
```

## Log File

In the log file, I can see that TFS runs csc.exe with the following options:

```
C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:...
```

But there are some that define the DEBUG constant:

```
C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference
```

## Question

Why does TFS seems to build a part of the project using the Debug configuration?

Comment: Are you using TFS 2008? MSBuild-based builds have been deprecated since TFS 2010.

Comment: @DanielMann The link we use to connect to it is http://tfs2010. I would really be surprised if it was an other version than 2010.